# cannot assign value to my `Map<String, String>` variable after json-decode

Tags: json, dart, flutter

I try to assign a value to my `Map<String, String>` variable after I json-encode it and then json-decode it. The following code example is a simplified reproduce;

```
import 'dart:convert';

String toJson(dynamic object) {
  var encoder = new JsonEncoder.withIndent("     ");
  return encoder.convert(object);
}

dynamic fromJson(String jsonString) {
  return json.decode(jsonString);
}

void main() {
  Map<String, String> data = {"hello": "world"};
  String jsonString = toJson(data);
  data = fromJson(jsonString);
  print(data);
}
```

When I run it, it fails with;

```
Unhandled exception:
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'
```

And [on this online editor](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/cbe2b312cbcd56af22d674abbcefbcde) it fails with a different error;

```
Uncaught exception:
TypeError: Instance of '_JsonMap': type '_JsonMap' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, String>'
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Workaround it,

I don't like it but it workaround the issue. Wrap the value returned by the `fromJson` function with `Map<String, String>.from(...)`

For example:

```
void main() {
  Map<String, String> data = {"hello": "world"};
  String jsonString = toJson(data);
  data = Map<String, String>.from(fromJson(jsonString));
  print(data);
}
```

Comment: Looks like type mismatch. 
It works if you replace 
`Map<String, String> data = {"hello": "world"};` 
with 
`Map<String, dynamic> data = {"hello": "world"};`